# Dot product of values from different arrays using BLAS in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, blas

I'm looking for fast way to do dot product and BLAS can be a option. But is there fast any way to do dot product of values from different arrays?

For example, let there are 4 different 1D array, a, b, c, d

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {5, 6, 7, 8}
c = {9, 10, 11, 12}
d = {13, 14, 15, 16}
```

and there is another array

```
k = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

what I want to do is calculate

```
ans1 = a[0]*k[0] + b[0]*k[1] + c[0]*k[2] + d[0]*k[3];
ans2 = a[1]*k[0] + b[1]*k[1] + c[1]*k[2] + d[1]*k[3];
```

and so on...

Doing this same calculation lots of time, but since the values in all arrays can be changed every iteration.
I'm trying to use ddot in BLAS and use pointer somehow but fail to do it.
Is there any way to use ddot without assign another array and copy the value to it such as,

```
e[0]=a[0];    e[1]=b[0];    e[2]=c[0];    e[3]=d[0];
```

then,

```
ans = ddot(4, e, 1, k, 1);
```

Also it is hard to make it as a 2D matrix because each 1D vectors(arrays) are located in different classes.
Please give me an advice to do this more efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your values known at compile time?

Comment: The values are keep changing in runtime and it cannot be known. That's why I keep copying each value to 1D array every iteration. But it takes time and the efficiency decreased...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the column vectors `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` in a 2D matrix M of the form

```
M = (a  b  c  d)
```

you can cast the problem into

```
ans = M k
```

where `ans = (ans1  ans2  ans3  ans4)`. This is a single matrix-vector multiplication for which the `dgemv` routine of BLAS is suitable.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I forgot to write that each 1D arrays are located in different classes. So it is hard to make in 2D matrix form.

Comment: @user270700 If you're not willing to modify your data structures, you'll still end up with the same number of copying into the 2D matrix. But you get to call only a single (more specialized) function for the whole operations and have a better chance of getting BLAS to do its magic.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need to consider your advice to modify the data structure.